# ngbTypeahead not working with Angular 6 and ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, rxjs6

I am trying to use `ngbTypeahead` on a basic Angular 6 application.  There aren't a whole lot of other dependencies in the application.  I keep getting the following method signature not found error...

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function
at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.pipe (Observable.js:91)
```

If I follow this line it ends up at this code which is the method it is looking for.

```
return pipeFromArray(operations)(this);
```

Here are the imports

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure, you have pipe operator added if you are chaining/single operator.

Comment: more info please? You might not be importing the angular bootstrap modules properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was simply because the filter code was wrong. Make sure that your filter method called on [ngbTypeahead] does indeed return an Observable. In my case I replaced the code and did not return anything resulting in the undefined issue.

Example:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : states.filter(v => new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(v)).splice(0, 10));`
```

[There is a plunker with working code here:](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nn54QCzKNcWCfd1n2kAu?p=preview)